# Match closing quote only if opening quote exists

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings similar in nature to `'foo = "bar"'`.  Right now when I am testing if these strings pass a certain regular expression, I am testing the quotes around 'bar' with `["|']?`, making the full RegEx in that area something along the lines of `["|']?(\w+)["|']?` (I am stripping out irrelevant expression parts for readability).

This means several things:

- The quotes around the word can be double quotes, single quotes, or nonexistent.
- Regardless of which they are, they are not "linked".  If a double quote is used on the left and no quote on the right this will still pass, etc.

My goal is to match the second quote based on the first.  I would very much like to implement this entirely with RegEx, though I understand I am approaching the limits of what it can do (as far as the JavaScript implementation goes).  I am quite familiar with lookaheads/behinds, but as I understand it these would only be relevant if the quotes were touching.  I am hoping that I understand them incorrectly.

P.S.:  I am only worried about modern browsers, so IE<10 support is a non-issue.

P.P.S:  I mentioned that I would like to do this with RegEx.  Please save yourself effort and do not give an alternative.  A "you cannot do this" would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write:

```
/(["'])\w+\1/
```

`\1` will only match a string that's identical to what the first [capture-group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (`(["'])`) captured.

Note that I removed the pipe character `|` from the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `["']`, because it seemed to be an error: the pipe character does not have any special meaning inside a character class. `["|']` is only correct if you want to be able to match e.g. `|bar|`.

Comment: Aha! I completely forgot you could do this!  Thanks a ton, this is _exactly_ what I was looking for.

Comment: Also thanks for correcting my use of the pipe.  I know they are used in groupings (foo|bar), and in my naïvety I thought they were in character classes as well.

Comment: doesn't this need `^$` anchors?

Comment: @Alnitak:  My question was admittedly contrived, and ruakh's answer was more than sufficient enough to give me what I needed in this case.  This is just a tiny part of a rather large expression (though I left that out of the OP, so you are correct to question it).

Comment: @Rαωs fair enough - I just wouldn't want to see some newbie come along and use this not realising it'll also match `oh'foo="bar"'crap`

Comment: @Alnitak: The question asked about matching the `"bar"` part of `'foo = "bar"'`. Adding `^` and `$` would prevent such matching. (And the OP seemed pretty clear on how to assemble a regex -- (s)he wrote of "stripping out irrelevant expression parts for readability" -- so I wasn't worried about that sort of thing. I originally planned to leave out the `/`, so as not to imply that this was a complete regex, but then the syntax-highlighting was wonky.)